# How can I use internal inner class from Viewmodel in View with a button in Kotlin?

Tags: xml, kotlin, mvvm, android-databinding, mediarecorder

I tried to make a dictaphone app usinghttps://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediarecorder with MVVM and databinding. I have class AudioRecordTest in view model and dont know how to use it from View to connect it to button from xml file

RecordViewModel.kt

```
package com.example.thedictaphone.viewmodels

import android.Manifest
import android.content.Context
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.media.MediaPlayer
import android.media.MediaRecorder
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.LinearLayout
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import java.io.IOException

private const val LOG_TAG = "AudioRecordTest"
private const val REQUEST_RECORD_AUDIO_PERMISSION = 200

class RecordViewModel: ViewModel() {
    //private val _name = MutableLiveData("Ada")
    //val name: LiveData<String> = _name

}

class AudioRecordTest : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var fileName: String = ""

    private var recordButton: RecordButton? = null
    private var recorder: MediaRecorder? = null

    private var playButton: PlayButton? = null
    private var player: MediaPlayer? = null

    // Requesting permission to RECORD_AUDIO
    private var permissionToRecordAccepted = false
    private var permissions: Array<String> = arrayOf(Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO)

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
        requestCode: Int,
        permissions: Array<String>,
        grantResults: IntArray
    ) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
        permissionToRecordAccepted = if (requestCode == REQUEST_RECORD_AUDIO_PERMISSION) {
            grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        } else {
            false
        }
        if (!permissionToRecordAccepted) finish()
    }

    fun onRecord(start: Boolean) = if (start) {
        startRecording()
    } else {
        stopRecording()
    }

    private fun onPlay(start: Boolean) = if (start) {
        startPlaying()
    } else {
        stopPlaying()
    }

    fun startPlaying() {
        player = MediaPlayer().apply {
            try {
                setDataSource(fileName)
                prepare()
                start()
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "prepare() failed")
            }
        }
    }

    private fun stopPlaying() {
        player?.release()
        player = null
    }

    private fun startRecording() {
        recorder = MediaRecorder().apply {
            setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC)
            setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP)
            setOutputFile(fileName)
            setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB)

            try {
                prepare()
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "prepare() failed")
            }

            start()
        }
    }

    private fun stopRecording() {
        recorder?.apply {
            stop()
            release()
        }
        recorder = null
    }

    internal inner class RecordButton(ctx: Context) : androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton(ctx) {

        var mStartRecording = true

        var clicker: OnClickListener = OnClickListener {
            onRecord(mStartRecording)
            text = when (mStartRecording) {
                true -> "Stop recording"
                false -> "Start recording"
            }
            mStartRecording = !mStartRecording
        }

        init {
            text = "Start recording"
            setOnClickListener(clicker)
        }
    }

    internal inner class PlayButton(ctx: Context) : androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton(ctx) {
        var mStartPlaying = true
        var clicker: OnClickListener = OnClickListener {
            onPlay(mStartPlaying)
            text = when (mStartPlaying) {
                true -> "Stop playing"
                false -> "Start playing"
            }
            mStartPlaying = !mStartPlaying
        }

        init {
            text = "Start playing"
            setOnClickListener(clicker)
        }
    }

    override fun onCreate(icicle: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(icicle)

        // Record to the external cache directory for visibility
        fileName = "${externalCacheDir?.absolutePath}/audiorecordtest.3gp"

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permissions, REQUEST_RECORD_AUDIO_PERMISSION)

        recordButton = RecordButton(this)
        playButton = PlayButton(this)
        val ll = LinearLayout(this).apply {
            addView(recordButton,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    0f))
            addView(playButton,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    0f))
        }
        setContentView(ll)
    }

    override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()
        recorder?.release()
        recorder = null
        player?.release()
        player = null
    }
}
```

FragmentRecord.kt

```
package com.example.thedictaphone.views

import android.Manifest
import android.content.Context
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.media.MediaPlayer
import android.media.MediaRecorder
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.LinearLayout
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat
import androidx.core.content.PackageManagerCompat.LOG_TAG
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
import androidx.navigation.fragment.findNavController
import com.example.thedictaphone.R
import com.example.thedictaphone.databinding.FragmentRecordBinding
import com.example.thedictaphone.viewmodels.AudioRecordTest
import com.example.thedictaphone.viewmodels.ListRecordsViewModel
import com.example.thedictaphone.viewmodels.RecordViewModel
import java.io.IOException


class FragmentRecord : Fragment() {

    private var _binding: FragmentRecordBinding? = null

    // This property is only valid between onCreateView and
    // onDestroyView.
    private val binding get() = _binding!!
    val viewModel by lazy { ViewModelProvider(this).get(RecordViewModel::class.java)}

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        _binding = FragmentRecordBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        binding.viewModel= viewModel
        binding.lifecycleOwner=this
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        binding.startRecord.setOnClickListener {
        }
        binding.pauseRecord.setOnClickListener {
        }
        binding.stopRecord.setOnClickListener {

        }
    }

    override fun onResume(){
        super.onResume()
        val mainActivity: MainActivity?=activity as? MainActivity
        mainActivity!!.binding.fab.hide()//make binding public
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }

}
```

fragment_record.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.example.thedictaphone.viewmodels.RecordViewModel"/>
    </data>

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".views.FragmentRecord">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="16dp">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/start_record"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:text="Record"

                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.052"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
<!--android:onClick="@{() -> viewModel.RecordButton}"-->

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/pause_record"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="22dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:text="Pause"

                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/start_record"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/stop_record"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:text="Play"

                android:onClick="PlayButton"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.912"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/pause_record"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
            
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
</layout>
```

I tried to use this:
`android:onClick="@{() -> viewModel.RecordButton}"`
to bind button to my class, but it says "Cannot find identifier 'RecordButton'"